# EF Core - How can I retrieve associated entities of an aggregate root?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-core-2.1

In my app I am trying to follow DDD whilst modelling a simple fund account.

The classes are

**FundAccount**

```
public Guid Id { get; set; }

private ICollection<AccountTransaction> _transactions = new List<AccountTransaction>();

public IReadOnlyCollection<AccountTransaction> Transactions => _transactions
            .OrderByDescending(transaction => transaction.TransactionDateTime).ToList();
```

**AccountTransaction**

```
public Guid Id { get; set; }

public decimal Amount { get; set; )
```

I am trying to retrieve the fund account from the database with the transactions included with the following:

```
var fundAccount = await _context.FundAccounts
                 .Include(a => a.Transactions)
                 .SingleAsync(a => a.Id == ...);
```

> When I retrieve the FundAccount (which has transactions in the database) `Transactions` has 0 `AccountTransaction`?

Can anyone see what I need to do here?

Comment: What is the relationship in the `AccrountTransaction` to `FoundAccount`? There isn't a property FoundAccountId... Is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

First, when using *domain logic" in the entity *data* model (which you shouldn't, but that's another story), make sure to configure EF Core to use [backing fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field) instead of properties (the default), by adding the following to the db context `OnModelCreating` override:

```
modelBuilder.UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
```

This btw has been recognized as issue and will be fixed in the 3.0 version - see [Breaking Changes - Backing fields are used by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field). But currently you have to include the above code.

Second, you have to change the backing field *type* to be compatible with the property type.

In your case, `ICollection<AccountTransaction>` is *not* compatible with `IReadOnlyCollection<AccountTransaction>`, because the former does not inherit the later for historical reasons. But the `List<T>` (and other collection *classes*) implement both interfaces, and since this is what you use to initialize the field, simply use it as a field type:

```
private List<AccountTransaction> _transactions = new List<AccountTransaction>();
```

With these two modifications in place, the collection navigation property will be correctly loaded by EF Core.