# EF Core with Sqlite Memory Database for testing throws "Collection is read-only" error - why?

Tags: c#, sqlite, integration-testing, xunit, ef-core-2.2

I'm writing integration test with ef core using sqlite memory database. Here is the code:

```cs
        public async Task GetCustomerAndRidesById_When_MultipleCustomersArePresent()
        {
            var connectionStringBuilder =
                new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder { DataSource = ":memory:" };
            var connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionStringBuilder.ToString());

            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TravelContext>()
                .UseSqlite(connection)
                .Options;

            var customer = _customerBuilder.WithDefaults();
            Customer customerFromRepo;

            using (var context = new TravelContext(options))
            {
                context.Database.OpenConnection();
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();

                await context.Customers.AddAsync(customer);

                await context.SaveChangesAsync();

                _output.WriteLine($"Customer ID: {customer.Id}");

                //var customerRepository = new CustomerRepository(context);
                //customerFromRepo = await customerRepository.GetByIdWithRidesAsync(customer.Id);
            }

            using (var context = new TravelContext(options))
            {
                var customerRepository = new CustomerRepository(context);
                try
                {
                    customerFromRepo = await customerRepository.GetByIdWithRidesAsync(customer.Id);
                }
                catch (System.Exception e)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            customerFromRepo.Should().BeEquivalentTo(customer);
            customerFromRepo.Rides.Should().HaveCount(customer.Rides.Count);
        }
```

The above code throws following error

> **Collection is read-only**

error. However if I comment out the second `using` block and uncomment the lines inside first `using` block, records are retrieved and test passes.

Here is my `Customer` class:

```cs
    public class Customer : BaseEntity<Guid>, IAggregateRoot
    {
        private Customer()
        {
            // required by EF
        }

        public Customer(string name, List<Ride> rides)
        {
            Name = name;
            _rides = rides;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        private readonly List<Ride> _rides = new List<Ride>();
        public IReadOnlyCollection<Ride> Rides => _rides.AsReadOnly();
    }
```

I'm puzzled. Can anyone explain why?

Thanks

[image: SQL Lite Error]

Comment: Similar reason as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57429933/ef-core-how-can-i-retrieve-associated-entities-of-an-aggregate-root/57431980#57431980. And same solution - `modelBuilder.UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);`

Comment: Above code works for me when I retrieve inside first using block. If I retrieve inside second using block it's throwing error. I'm following DDD approach and I have all backing fields. Can you please explain further on how the answer in above link relate to my case? I'm new to these stuffs and need better understanding. Please assist

Comment: It doesn't matter if it works in some particular case. Most likely in the first scenario the object you added is tracked(cached) along with related collection. In the second scenario there is no cache, so EF really needs to load the object from the database and it fails as expected because your collection property is read only. I knew you are following DDD since you are not using the "normal" for EF `ICollection` property which has no any issue at all. But when you use `IReadOnlyCollection` property implemented like yours, it's crucial to let EF Core use the backing field to load it with data.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev I have a backing field set as you can see in the code. `private readonly List<Ride> _rides = new List<Ride>()`. Am I missing something? Please guide me

Comment: Your backing field is/was fine. All you need is to enable the usage of it as explained in the link - override `OnModelCreating` and add `modelBuilder.UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);` there.

Comment: Many Thanks @IvanStoev . Thanks for teaching. you earned my respect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling the below configuration fixes the issue.

```cs
var navigation = builder.Metadata.FindNavigation(nameof(Customer.Rides));
navigation.SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
```

Credits and Thanks to [Ivan Stoev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5202563/ivan-stoev) for guidance.